# How to show data in sql on Label! (Python, Sql, tkinter)

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def data(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('qlcsnv.db')
    myCursor = conn.cursor()
    myCursor.execute("Select *from csnv")
    row=myCursor.fetchall()
    print(len(row))
```

**I want show print(len(row)) on label:**

```
self.data2=Label(self.frame4,text="TỔNG: "+ self.data(),font=('Time New Roman', 9, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='#D0C4DE')
self.Tongdata2.place(x=5, y=40, width=70)
```

**But on label show: DATA: None**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return nothing from `data()`, you're just printing it into the console, so `self.data()` returns `None`. Try

```
def data(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('qlcsnv.db')
    myCursor = conn.cursor()
    myCursor.execute("Select *from csnv")
    row=myCursor.fetchall()
    return len(row)
```

Comment: Problem has been solved. Thanks you so much bro!